# Weak Convergence in space $ C_0$ proof

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Definition**: Weak convergence- If a sequence $x_n\in X$ converges weakly then if $x_n\to x_0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$ for $f\in X'$
>
> **Proposition**: If a sequence converges by the norm then it converges weakly.
> Proof: $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|=|f(x_n-x_0)|\leqslant ||f|||x_n-x_0||\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Then my doubt arises in the following example: Consider the space $C_0$(space of all the sequence that converge to 0) with norm $max$. $e_k=(0,0,0,...,1,0,0,0,0...0)$ then $||e_i-e_j||=1,i\neq j$, where $e_1,e_2...$ is a basis of $C_0$

$f\in (C_0)'\simeq l_1$

$f(x)=\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}x_k\xi_k\:\:\:\:\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}\xi_k<\infty$

$\xi_k=f(e_k)$

Then $|f(e_k)|\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$

**Questions:**

**1)** How does the author establishes $\xi_k=f(e_k)$?

**2)** Is correct to assume that since $|f(e_k)|\to 0$ the sequences converge weakly but not strongly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  For $e_k=(x_n)\in C_0$, we have $x_n=1$ if $n=k$ and $x_n=0$ otherwise.  Thus we have $f(e_k)=\sum_{n}x_n\xi_n=\xi_k$.

**2)** From $|f(e_k)|\to 0$ you can conclude directly that $\{e_k\}$ converges weakly.  To show it does not converge strongly you need to do some more work, presumably already covered (or assumed) by the author.

Comment: I think that the sequence does not converge by the norm once $||e_k-e_i||=1$ for $i\neq k$. Is it right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding point 1 in your explanation. Why is $e_k=(x_n)$?

Comment: $e_k$ is just a sequence, I'm saying this sequence is $(x_n)$